# How to do a flatMap with an NonEmptyArray in fp-ts way?

Tags: typescript, fp-ts

I have a class like this:

```js
class ValidationError {
  constructor(
    public readonly errors: NonEmptyArray<string>,
  ) {}
}
```

And have a `NonEmptyArray<ValidationError>`, but I want to transform it into a single `ValidationError` with all the errors from the NEA.

In a normal way, I could do it:

```js
const allErrors = validationErrorArr.flatMap(e => e.errors)
const newValidationError = new ValidationError(allErrors)
```

But what's the best way to do it in the fp way?

Comment: What's non-FP about what you're doing? What are you expecting to do differently?

Comment: I'm studying fp-ts and trying to implement somethings in the FP way.

Comment: I think the code is reasonably "FP" but I can understand wanting to keep the "non-empty" aspect of the type around. I suspect using the browser's `flatMap` function will lose the "non-empty" aspect, whereas the code from the library will keep the type information

Comment: @Souperman but there is no type information for contents of ValidationError so there's no way to preserve the non-empty aspect. You're just going to end up with ValidationError in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Using `fp-ts` and functions from the `NonEmptyArray` module, you could write a function to collect the errors like:

```js
import { NonEmptyArray, flatten, map } from 'fp-ts/lib/NonEmptyArray';

const collectErrors = flow(
  map((error: ValidationError) => error.errors),
  flatten,
  (errors) => new ValidationError(errors),
);
```

If you're interested in writing something fully "point-free" you can add some helpers, although in general, point-free is not always a goal that should be sought after if it's going to make the code harder to understand.

```js
class ValidationError {
  constructor(
    public readonly errors: NonEmptyArray<string>,
  ) {}
  public static create(errors: NonEmptyArray<string>) {
    return new ValidationError(errors);
  }
}

const prop = <T, K extends keyof T>(key: K) => (t: T): T[K] => t[key];

// We can now write this "point-free"
const collectErrors = flow(
  map(prop<ValidationError, 'errors'>('errors')),
  flatten,
  ValidationError.create,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The fp-ts terminology for flatmap is `chain`, so

```js
import { chain } from 'fp-ts/NonEmptyArray'

const collectErrors = flow(
  chain((_: ValidationError) => _.errors),
  a => new ValidationError(a)
)
```

This is exactly what you need. You could needlessly complicate things by creating some sort of Semigroup instance and then running `fold` over the semigroup instance and the NEA.